# Share and Use Variables between Agent job and agentless job in Azure CLASSIC Release pielines

Tags: azure-pipelines

Note : We are using CLASSIC Azure Devops release pipeline

We have an agent job does two app service deployment
Next step is a Agentless manual intervention

We dont need to run this Agentless Manual intervention to run on 2 condition
1 , 'ManualValidation' variable in varible goup is true
2, IF the task2 in Agent job is scuccess

other wise we don't need to run the agentless manual intervention and it needs to be failed status so that next Agent-2 job should not run it has condition (Only when all the previous jobs succeeded)

**********Clarification ***********
1, Since its a classic pipeline ,I believe cannot use a output variable
how do I check two values in variable condition in Agentless job , is there any property will say that last task from previous job failed and accessible in Agentjob so that I can use in and condition with variables

2, What if the Task2 in Agent-Job1 fails , will it stop running the AgentJob-2 tasks since it has condition (Only when all the previous jobs succeeded)

- AgentJob-1
  Taksk1
  Task2
- Agentless Job
  (eq(variables['ManualValidation'],'true')  Run this job (Custom condition Using Variable expressions)
  Manual Intervention Task
- AgentJob-2
  Taksk1
  Task2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to pass variables from agent job to agentless job in classic pipeline

My requirement is execute the agentless only

1, if all the tasks in inAgentjob-1 succeed and library variable "ManualValidation" is true

2, it has to skip Agentless job or should not run

if any of  tasks in inAgentjob-1 fails   &&  "ManualValidation"== true
This will in turn skips the Agentjob-2  from running

So instead of variable passing from the Agent job , found some thing in Microsoft articles

added a variable expression like below and it seems to be working

and(succeeded(),eq(variables['ManualValidation'],'true'))

- Agentjob-1

  ```
    Task-1

    Task-2
  ```
- Agentlessjob
- Agentjob-2

  ```
     Task-1

     Task-2
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method in Azure DevOps Release Pipeline can share and use the Variable between agent job and agentless job based on the result of the task 2 in agent job 1.

When we use variable group, we can share the same variable among all jobs in the release pipeline. However, since the release pipeline does not support updating and using the variables of the variable group during the running process, we cannot update the variables for agentless job according to the results of task2 in agent job1.

Based on your requirement, here is a workaround that can meet your requirement:

You can enable the `Continue on error` option for task 1. And set the `Only when all the previous jobs succeeded` for agentless job.

In this case, when the task 1 in agent job 1 failed, it will continue to run task 2 in agent job 1.

If task 2 is running successfully, it will show as the status: **Partially succeeded** and it will run the agentless job.

For example:

[image]

If the task 2 is running failed, it will stop the pipeline and not run the agentless job.

For example:

[image]